# system.linq.enumaerable+<Cast... in combobox C#

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, linq, visual-studio-2019

I have a SQL query that reads string data from a SQL Express DB (Changing over to Azure). Once the data is retrieved, I read it into an array and then display the contents of the array in a combo-box. i am not receiving any error however, in the combo-box, an extra field is displayed and I cannot fgure out how to prevent this.

I have a class for the array that is created with {get; set;}. Below is the actual code for the main program:

```
LocationList[] address1 = null;

string sql = @"SELECT Address1 FROM DN";

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connectionString))
{
    connectionString.Open();
    using (var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var list = new List<LocationList>();
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(new LocationList { Address1 = sqlReader.GetString(0) });
        }
        address1 = list.Distinct().ToArray();
        sqlReader.Close();
    }
    connectionString.Close();  
}

cbTransferTo.Items.Add(address1.Cast<string>());
```

[image]

Also, every time I click on the drop down, an extra item is added without me having to start and stop the program. It's not supposed to do this and I can't find the issue.

What the program needs to do is only display the contents it gets from the SQL database table which is a list of locations.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "Also [...]" - please ask *one question* per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a *single item* to the combobox, but that single item is the return value from `Cast<string>()`, which is a sequence. The type doesn't override `ToString()`, so you're getting the name of the type instead.

What I believe you *want* to do is add all the items to the combobox:

```cs
foreach (var location in address1)
{
    cbTransferTo.Add(location.Address1);
}
```

Note that if you just iterate over the result of `Cast<string>()`, I'd expect an exception anyway - because `address1` is a sequence of `LocationList` items, not strings. It's not clear why you're using `LocationList` at all though - I suspect it would be simpler just to use a string to start with. Simpler code would be:

```cs
string sql = @"SELECT Address1 FROM DN";

List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connectionString))
{
    connectionString.Open();
    using (var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            addresses.Add(sqlReader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    connectionString.Close();  
}

foreach (var address in addresses.Distinct())
{
    cbTransferTo.Add(address);
}
```

It would be even better to use `DISTINCT` in your SQL, so that you can get the database to do the de-duping rather than fetching all the data into your program and *then* de-duping...

Answer (score 0):

The call to `address1.Cast<string>()` returns an `IEnumerable` implementing type, not a string. You're adding this type to your combo box and it's being rendered by calling `ToString` which is returning the name of the type.

As it it your code is buggy. `address1` is a sequence of `LocationList`, not a `string`. Because the call to `Cast` is lazy evaluated you're not seeing the error.